# Split One View Controller Into Multiple Classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am about to start work on a new app which is going to have thousands of lines of code.

I don't want this code to be in just one .h and .m class files but rather split into several.

Is this even at all possible, and if so, please enlighten me as i have been struggling with this for days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, identify the specific roles your controller fills and see which ones make sense to break out into separate controller classes. For example you might have a controller to act as the delegate and data source of a table view or to manage one of your UIViewController's subviews.

Whatever controller classes you define then should be subclasses of NSObject, not UIViewController. Take a look at http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/ and see if you find that helpful.